# how to perform versioning content between users?

Tags: 7, files, nodes, version-control

I need to create a content type "Project Software". Users can upload source code to their projects as a portfolio editing option. In one project can participate more users. So I need a solution for versioning the project so that it can be shared for online editing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [project](http://drupal.org/project/project) module. This is used on the drupal site as well.